# Bootstrap error messages aren't working with php if

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and I want to show  error messages based on specific conditions. I am currently using:

```
<?php if ($credits < 100) { ?>
    <div id="alert"class="alert alert-error"> Some error occured! </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="alert" class="alert alert-success"> No error occured. </div>
<?php } ?>
```

If $credits are **less** than 100, it just displays displays *Some error occured!* normally (with white bg) and so, "alert alert-error" doesn't do anything.  But if $credits are **more** than 100 it displays *No error occured.* with green success bg.

How can I fix it?

Comment: @Juhana Thx! i used alert alert-danger and now it's working

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
alert alert-danger
```

instead of

```
alert alert-error
```

and now it is working :)